# Does a U.S. citizen have any access to DHS records of entry?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, i-94

I am a citizen of USA. I have returned to the country at least seven times in four years. When I enter from Mexico (or Peru via Mexico), no one has asked me for an I94. All other entries, I have been given one before arrival and asked for it after arrival. Once I lost it and was required to obtain and fill out another.

But [their search pages](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) claim there is no record of me.

Do they just throw them away? Where/how do they record our ins and outs? How do we obtain/view that? As I understand it, we have a legal right to view information kept about us. If that's true, access to it would be convenient if some other country accuses us of overstay.

Comment: I think you're confusing the I-94, which is not required for citizens, with CBP Form 6059B, the Customs declaration.

Comment: You are correct.  I did an image search for I94 and didn't blow up the image.  when it's small, it looks the same.

Answer (score 9):

As a US citizen, you do not have an I-94; those are only for non-citizens. You fill out a [customs declaration form 6059B](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/sample-declaration-form) (or a simplified electronic equivalent if you use the APC kiosks, Global Entry, or Mobile Passport Control) when entering by air.

You can request various records that CBP has for on you by filing [a Privacy Act request](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia). Here's [a news article](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/05/ask-ars-can-i-see-what-the-feds-know-about-where-ive-traveled/) detailing the types of information you'll get back.

EDIT: Couple of follow-ups to the article cited:

https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/07/ars-editor-learns-feds-have-his-old-ip-addresses-full-credit-card-numbers/

https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/surprise-surprise-my-online-metadata-actually-reveals-where-ive-been/

Comment: Interesting article.  I am now attempting to find the promised sequel.

Comment: Found it.  Full credit card numbers in plaintext, and other unpleasant things.    I've edited my own request, but don't know whether I'll have time to take to a print shop and mail before I leave again (nine days).